# Non-blocking read of a byte from stdin

Tags: c#, mono, stdin, nonblocking

I would like to read a byte (or character) from stdin (Standard Input) of C# mono process in the following manner:

- If there's already bytes available for reading from stdin, return the first one
- If there are no bytes available for reading from stdin, proceed without waiting for anything or blocking
- If there are threads or async, it should be succint and provably correct drop-in solution of getting a single byte on demand
- stdin may be pipe or file so `Console.KeyAvailable` won't do

Thanks.

Comment: There is no platform-independent way to do async stdin I/O, which is why the BCL doesn't try. "Read operations on the standard input stream execute synchronously. That is, they block until the specified read operation has completed." Can it be implemented on Mono? Probably, if you like P/Invoke and `#if` to take care of the various platforms. It's almost certainly not worth doing it as opposed to spinning up a thread to wrap the sync operation, though (and using `Console.IsInputRedirected` to distinguish that case).

Comment: @JeroenMostert writing more code is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.
I'll go for a really succint example of how it can be done in shortest possible way.
The idea is to avoid spending any non-trivial amount of code or effort on the problem.

Come on, it's 2017! And we can't read a byte from a stream without threads or blocking!?

Comment: It is indeed 2017, but cross-platform, non-blocking console I/O is just not a feature that has been in heavy demand -- ever. The fashion has always been console applications that serenely process their input in a synchronous, single-threaded manner. If you're content with polling rather than true async (as you are) it's fairly easy to do on both Unix and Win32 (though not, of course, in the same way, that would be too easy), but .NET goes for the lowest common denominator, which doesn't help. I couldn't come up with a trivial solution in 10 minutes. Not saying there *isn't* one.

Comment: Came up with a not-as-trivial solution while thinking about it some more. I would love for there to be better answers, maybe this inspires someone.

Comment: @JeroenMostert polling is not an option in another thread's event loop where muxing of events from different directions should take place.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Reactive Extensions! ...maybe. They can be overkill.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm not sure XNA supports that. It has this thing against trying anything remotely weird.

Comment: If your intended platform is XNA, consider tagging with `xna` and possibly giving more details about what you're doing, because it's quite likely people have already solved similar problems in that specific context. (I know nothing about XNA other than that it exists.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert it's actually MonoGame but MonoGame questions don't get any attention.

Comment: Bounty or no bounty, show your research effort. 0 code or anything. You're just like: I want 'this' - thanks

Comment: @EpicKip imagine I had five takes at the problem, all of which failed. Do you really expect five code snippets in the question? Why would like to read that? Do you expect me to pick one? Which one if none works?

Comment: @alamar Go read the site's rules before you argue with me on this

Comment: @alamar And fyi, if someone has a problem and posts code *its expected not to work* but at least a start to something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided your platform has an implementation of `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`, here's one easy if not exactly efficient way to do it:

```
class ConsoleReader {
  private readonly BlockingCollection<int> buffer = new BlockingCollection<int>(1);
  private readonly Thread readThread;
  public ConsoleReader() {
    readThread = new Thread(() => {
      if (Console.IsInputRedirected) {
        int i;
        do {
          i = Console.Read();
          buffer.Add(i);
        } while (i != -1);
      } else {
        while (true) { 
          var consoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
          if (consoleKeyInfo.KeyChar == 0) continue;  // ignore dead keys
          buffer.Add(consoleKeyInfo.KeyChar);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public void Start() {
    readThread.Start();
  }

  public int? Next {
    get {
      int result;
      return buffer.TryTake(out result, 0) ? result : default(int?);
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: this answer has not actually been tested on Mono, and only briefly on the full .NET platform.
You can spice this up with a `Task` instead of a `Thread`, proper cancellation etc., but that won't change the central inefficiency of explicitly waiting on a synchronous operation (which `Console.Read` and `Console.ReadKey` both are). Portable asynchronous console I/O is not offered by .NET itself. Implementing that yourself across platforms (using the OS features) is possible, but decidedly nontrivial.

Comment: Actually, there's portable asynchronous console I/O in the form of Console.KeyAvailable. It's the input redirect scenario that gives me trouble - non-blocking read from input redirect (== file) stream.

Comment: @alamar: `Console.KeyAvailable` is indeed *non-blocking*, which is not the same thing as *asynchronous*, which has a rather distinct meaning in .NET -- there is no `Console.BeginReadKey()` or `Console.ReadKeyAsync()`. There *is*, however, `Stream.BeginRead()`, and `Console.OpenStandardInput()`. The console stream is still synchronous, but `.BeginRead()` will always provide an async-over-sync wrapper. That may achieve what you want.

Comment: @alamar: note that, when reading from the console, neither `Console.Read()` nor the input stream will return anything until a whole line has been read, even though you're asking for just one character. This is why `.OpenStandardInput()`/`.BeginRead()` isn't a universal solution. But you can combine that with `.IsInputRedirected`.

Comment: non-blocking is what is desired, not asynchronous. The idea is to get the value where it is needed. Asynchronous can only deliver value in context where it is no longer useful. Surely I can store that value somewhere, but that already sounds like a lot of infrastructure. But if you can throw together a solution including storage, would it be shorter/more straightforward?

`Console.ReadKey` happily reads a single byte from console without waiting for whole line.

Comment: My solution *has* storage -- the last key read is stored in the `BlockingCollection` and won't be retrieved until you call `.Next`. If there is no key (yet), it won't return anything. If input has been redirected from a stream, `.Next` will always return a character, until the stream is done. So either it's exactly what you want, or I just don't understand your scenario, in which case I encourage you to play around with this code yourself.

Comment: "If input has been redirected from a stream, .Next will always return a character, until the stream is done"

But what if input is redirected as a pipe to another process's output which is not writing anything yet?

Comment: @alamar: Then it will return `null`, because `Console.Read` will still be waiting and `buffer.TryTake` will return immediately. `.Next` will always return a character *if one is available*.